# SQL using condition with COUNT()

Tags: mysql

I have recently started learning SQL and I've come across a bit of a problem, which I'm sure is not very difficult, but I've yet to find an answer. Anyway. Say we have a table:
awesomeMovies

```
Dir    -- Title
George || Once
Lucas  || Upon
Star   || In a 
Wars   || In a
```

etc...

If we do:

```
SELECT COUNT(title) FROM awesomeMovies GROUP BY title;
```

we'd get:

```
1

1

2
```

So my question basically is:
How can I use a WHERE statement along with the COUNT statement to only show lines that exist in the table twice?
I mean,

```
SELECT COUNT(title) FROM awesomeMovies GROUP BY title WHERE COUNT(title)>1;
```

Doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query will select the count of only those awesome movies which exist more than one time in the `awesomeMovies` table.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(title)
FROM awesomeMovies
GROUP BY title
HAVING  COUNT(title) > 1;
```

**Note:**

The actual execution of SQL statements is a bit tricky. However, the standard does specify the order of interpretation of elements in the query. This is basically in the order that you specify, although I think having and group by could come after select:

```
 - FROM clause
 - WHERE clause
 - SELECT clause
 - GROUP BY clause
 - HAVING clause
 - ORDER BY clause
```

Here's a visualization of mysql query builder:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `Having`:

```
SELECT title,COUNT(title) 
FROM awesomeMovies 
GROUP BY title 
having COUNT(title)>1;
```

`Having` is use to filter group data.